# Should I Change my Research Focus?

Tags: thesis, mathematics, research-topic

I just finished my first semester in a PhD program in Pure and Applied mathematics. My initial focus was on probability, statistics, modeling, and machine learning. To this end I took a course in (Modern) Probability, Nonlinear Optimization, and the mandatory Functional Analysis. Based on my performance in these courses my advisor suggested that I should consider maybe switching to a different focus, as he thinks I will struggle to pass the qualifying exam (specifically in the two elective courses Probability and Nonlinear Optimization).

However, I do not believe my scores reflect my real capability or interest in the subjects, but rather reflect a gap in what was taught and what was tested. I am sure I could study really hard and succeed.

I am posting here to get a second opinion on whether or not I should change my focus, or if I should stick with it and double down and study really hard. I posted on math.stackexchange and was advised to post here for a second opinion. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984219/what-are-some-possible-phd-research-areas-based-on-these-course-pairs?noredirect=1#comment8221305_3984219)

What would you advise? Should I change my focus to another one that I might have a better synergy with? Thank you!

Comment: Listen to your advisor. I have found that going through the doors that open for me, even if those doors are different from the ones that I initially had in mind, has never served me wrong. Don't be the person who won't walk through the door because they insist a different one should be opening.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try my best to follow their advice. The only problem is figuring out a new area to focus on. I will try to overcome any issues I encounter and find a path to success. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This requires self-evaluation and introspection. That being said, don't let a bad grade in a course deter you from pursuing your interest(s) in mathematics. In my experience, the first semester in a PhD program is usually the worst in terms of grades. This is because you are still trying to adjust from undergraduate math to graduate. You may also have grading/TA duties, so time management skills are essential.

Comment: @LordVader007 thank you for your advice. It was my first semester working as a TA too, and I definitely felt overwhelmed. I will do some introspection and will see if the probability / statistics courses are what I am really passionate about. I will also see if I can optimize my time-management to really do well next semester. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your advisor's advice is probably worth taking. They know you better than we do.

But your current goal is to get a doctorate. The specific sub field is less important than that goal. You can always take up a different specialty later if it isn't too different.

Find a path to success. Examine the obstacles (exams, ...) and find a way through them. You may have made some judgmental errors, but don't make any more.

But to find that path, in mathematics, find a field in which you have true insight into how things work. Math insight isn't general. You can have deep insight into one field (analysis) and little in another (algebra).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will not give up.